# Italicizing a specific part of a concatenation for a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am just beginning to experiment with VBA and wanted to create code that italicized the title of presentations in a concatenation, given that Excel normally does not allow that to happen. I also want to paste the output in another worksheet.

The current code is what I created to paste the concatenation output in a specific column of the SAME worksheet (named "Presentations Table"), but I am having trouble figuring out how to:

1. paste the concatenated output in a specific column of a different worksheet (named "Presentations Cited") starting from the first row and column in the same workbook
2. how to get it to automatically italicize ONLY the text from the title column. All other text in the concatenation should not be italicized.

I would be grateful for any help!

Table structure:
[image]

Current output:
[image]

```
Worksheets("Presentations Table").Range("a3", Worksheets("Presentations Table").Range("a3").End(xlDown)).Select
Row = 1
col = 1
For Each Cell In Selection
Authors = Cells(Row, col)
Year_Month = Cells(Row, col + 1)
Title = Cells(Row, col + 2)
Presentation_Type = Cells(Row, col + 3)
Event_Name = Cells(Row, col + 4)
Location = Cells(Row, col + 5)

Worksheets("Presentations Table").Cells(Row, col + 2) = Authors & " (" & Year_Month & "). " & Title & ". " & Presentation_Type & " at the " & Event_Name & ", " & Location & "."

Row = Row + 1
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format text strings in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405988/how-do-you-format-text-strings-in-vba)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you format text/strings in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405988/how-do-you-format-text-strings-in-vba)

Comment: Those are not duplicates. I couldn't find anything in them to help me with formatting specific parts of a concatenation that draws from a specific column, nor anything on how to have it transferred to another worksheet...

Comment: Your question title was Italics strings... , the answers in the link are pertinent to your first sentence and second question.  Your question is really two questions which should be posted separately.  The code you have looks like it should work.  If it isn't working tell us what's wrong with it - doesn't compile?...run-time error?...unexpected output?

Comment: I clearly said the code as is works for making the concatenation happen. My question is how do I format the title, which is from a specific column that makes up part of the concatenation, after it has been concatenated? The answers in the links do not answer anything about concatenations from what I can see. I provided my current code in the hopes that someone would be able to advise on what specifically I need to do and where that new segment of code would be placed in what I do have. First sentence also says I am only just beginning to experiment with VBA...sorry if I said something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste them as HTML formatting with something like this (not tested):

```
Dim c As Range, s As String    
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Presentations Table").Cells(3)

s = "<html>"
While c <> ""
    s = s & c & " (" & c(, 2) & "). <i>" & c(, 3) & "</i>. " & c(, 4) & " at the " & c(, 5) & ", " & c(, 6) & ".</br>"
    set c = c(2) ' the cell below c
Wend

With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    .SetText s
    .PutInClipboard
End With

c(2).PasteSpecial
```